# Which equation does this process satisfy?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

1) Which equation does the following process satisfy:
$$Y_t:=W_t^{4}$$
Where $W_t$ is Wiener process.

2) Prove that $$\mathbb{E}W_t^{4}=3t^2$$

Using Ito formula for $Y_t$ is a good point to start?

**My attempt:**

Obviously
$$ dW_t=0dt+1dW_t$$
Let
$$F(W_t,t)=W_t^4$$
Now using Ito formula
$$dF(W_t,t)=(0+0+6W_t^2)dt+4W_t^3dW_t$$
Now we integrate each side
$$Y_t=\int_0^t 6W_s^2ds+\int_0^t4W_s^3dW_s$$
And when it comes to 1) that is our equation?

2) $$\mathbb{E}Y_t=\mathbb{E}\int_0^t 6W_s^2ds+\mathbb{E}\int_0^t4W_s^3dW_s$$
I don't know what I can use next. Any hint? Can i go with expectation inside the integral?

Comment: "Using Ito formula for Yt is a good point to start?" Yes. What did you actually try?

Comment: I've edited 1st post. Could you check the first part?

Comment: First part ok. I wonder why you did not include it in your question from the start...

Comment: Sorry, I have a problem with self-confidence...I'll try the second part

Comment: Edited the second part

Comment: Try the most obvious: the part W^3dW is a m--t--g--e hence...

Comment: Is equal to zero?